# Cloud Firestore - Python - Performing simple Where query always returns Query object

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know this question may sound silly, but how can I properly query data using the Firebase Admin SDK (Cloud Firestore) with Python?

Yes, I have read the docs here:

- [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)
- [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

My database:

[image: Database]

My code:

```
existing_post = db.collection(u'posts').where(u'id', u'==', u'BpzIbkqAkk0').get()
print(existing_post)
```

I also tried omitting the .get() method, but also getting the same result each time.

All I've been getting is

```
<google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.query.Query object at 0x10e7aab00>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `[x for x in existing_post]`?

Comment: You need to loop through the result and call "to_dict()" on each element as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo, it sure did work after the loop. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Gerardo's comment has lead me to the right direction. Here's the working code:

```
existing_posts = db.collection(u'posts').where(u'id', u'==', u'BpzIbkqAkk0').get()
for post in existing_posts:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(post.id, post.to_dict()))
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to retrieve all the documents from the collections?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert generator object into dictionary format using `to_dict()`.
Then you can easily access whatever value you want.

```
existing_posts = db.collection(u'posts').document(u'id').get()
result=existing_posts.to_dict()
id='BpzIbkqAkk0'
result_id=result[id]
```

try this it may help you.